# Jenkins via Helm on GKE creates and does not remove slave pod for every build

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Jenkins setup on GKE installed via [standard Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins). My builds are consistently failing which I'm trying to troubleshoot, but in addition to that a new slave pod is created on every build attempt (with pod name like `jenkins-slave-3wsb7`). Almost all of them go to a `Completed` state after build fails, and then the pod lingers in my GKE dash and in list of pods from `kubectl get pods`. I currently have 80+ pods showing as a result.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a work around to clean up old Completed pods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the workaround to clean up completed pods :

```
kubectl delete pod NAME --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: I know I can manually delete each pod, but that doesn't help or seem sustainable in a CI/CD pipeline where builds and their related pods are continuously being spawned.

Comment: Its just a workaround. It doesnt have to be done manually. You could always deploy a kubernetes CronJob that does the cleanup. That would work with your CI/CD setup. But then again, this is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kubernetes 1.12 or later. The [`ttlSecondsAfterFinished`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically) Job spec was conveniently introduced. Note that it's 'alpha' in 1.12.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-with-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100 <====
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myjob
        image: myimage
        command: ["run_some_batch_job"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```